# Locking access to another class, from run method

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

fairly complex code but it's a very simple issue.

I have a thread, this is its run method:

```
public void run() //gets pages and writes to them
{ // i printed the pageId of every process to check they are running at the same time and competing for resources
    for(ProcessCycle currentCycle : processCycles.getProcessCycles())
    {
        Long[] longArray = new Long[currentCycle.getPages().size()];
        try {
            Page<byte[]>[] newPages = mmu.getPages(currentCycle.getPages().toArray(longArray));
            for(int i = 0; i < newPages.length; i++)
            {
                MMULogger.getInstance().write("GP:P" + id + " " + currentCycle.getPages().get(i) + " " + Arrays.toString(currentCycle.getData().get(i)), Level.INFO);
            }
            List<byte[]> currentPageData = currentCycle.getData();
            System.out.println("process id " + id);
            for(int i = 0; i < newPages.length;i++)
            {
                byte[] currentData = currentPageData.get(i);
                newPages[i].setContent(currentData);
            }
            Thread.sleep(currentCycle.getSleepMs());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

don't bother reading all of it. just notice that after the mmu.getpages there is a for loop.

While a process is inside the for loop, i want to lock access to mmu.getpages for all other threads. synchronized is no good since my original process is no longer in mmu, but in the for loop, and reentrantlock might be a good idea but I'm unfamiliar with the syntax and ran into some issues.

long story short - how do i make all other threads wait while some thread is inside the for loop after mmu.getpages?

Comment: You have three for loops, which one do you mean? The first for loop over `newPages`?

Comment: Yes. the first one, over newPages, just below the mmu.getpages

Comment: The code is somewhat broken by design. It is counter-intuitive and error-prone to lock something within a getter (e.g. if one does not un-lock the lock/semaphor/whatever after `getPages(...)` was called, nobody will be able to call `getPages(...)` ever again). Could you elaborate a little bit more about what you are trying to do? This seems to be an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I chose an approach like this:

```
private Object lock = new Object();
public void run() //gets pages and writes to them
{ // i printed the pageId of every process to check they are running at the same time and competing for resources
    for(ProcessCycle currentCycle : processCycles.getProcessCycles())
    {
        Long[] longArray = new Long[currentCycle.getPages().size()];
        try {
            synchrnonized(lock) {
                Page<byte[]>[] newPages = mmu.getPages(currentCycle.getPages().toArray(longArray));
                for(int i = 0; i < newPages.length; i++)
                {
                    MMULogger.getInstance().write("GP:P" + id + " " + currentCycle.getPages().get(i) + " " + Arrays.toString(currentCycle.getData().get(i)), Level.INFO);
                }
            }
            List<byte[]> currentPageData = currentCycle.getData();
            System.out.println("process id " + id);
            for(int i = 0; i < newPages.length;i++)
            {
                byte[] currentData = currentPageData.get(i);
                newPages[i].setContent(currentData);
            }
            Thread.sleep(currentCycle.getSleepMs());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if there is a better way. This will only work as expected when all threads share the same instance of this object, otherwise you have to make `lock` a static member variable.

Comment: I copied your code and it still allows access to mmu.getpages. the threads do not share the same instance. changing it to private static Object lock = new Object(); didnt make things better.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. while threadA is inside the for loop, i want to lock all other threadsfrom doing mmu.getpages, so shouldnt it also be in the synchronized block?

Comment: Then it looks like your threads use different classloaders. As a concequence you need to have an `Object` on which to lock that is shared by all threads. The variable `mmu` might do it. Otherwise there is just not enough code to guess.

Comment: @hotzst OP did not say that `getPages()` on the `mmu`-object is only called within the given code-snippet. If the same method is called on the same `mmu`-Object somewhere else, your approach cannot work. It has nothing to do with different classloaders.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) might be a best approach.

Something like this:

```
public class MmuClass {

    private ReadWriteLock blockGetPages =  new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public byte [] getPages(...) {
        try{ 
           blockGetPages.readLock().lock();
           // ...
           // ...
           // ...
           return result;
        finally{ 
           blockGetPages.readLock().unlock(); 
        }
    }

    public void lockAccessToGetPages(){
        blockGetPages.writeLock().lock();
    }

    public void unlockAccessToGetPages(){
        blockGetPages.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

and

```
Page<byte[]>[] newPages = mmu.getPages(currentCycle.getPages().toArray(longArray));
try{
     mmu.lockAccessToGetPages();
     for(int i = 0; i < newPages.length; i++) {
      MMULogger.getInstance().write("GP:P" + id + " " + currentCycle.getPages().get(i) + " " + Arrays.toString(currentCycle.getData().get(i)), Level.INFO);
   }
} finally{
    mmu.unlockAccessToGetPages();
}
```

In this solutions all "readers" can simultaneously call `getPages()`, the access is blocked after calling `lockAccessToGetPages()` and unblocked after calling `unlockAccessToGetPages()`. If one thread locks the object in write mode, only this thread has access to the method. If some thread tries to lock it in write mode, must wait until all readers, which are currently "inside" the metod, finish their fork and leave the method.